# finding missing dates between sequences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find the missing gap between the month of December and fill the gap using a SQL query

I have the followin query and it needs tweeking because it is still not correct here is what i wrote

```
CREATE TABLE #BenfitDim(MemberName varchar(30),Memberkey int,MemberEffectiveDate DATETIME,
    MemberTerminationDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('tom',231,'2012-11-18','2012-11-23')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('tom',231,'2012-11-24','2012-12-12')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('tom',231,'2013-01-01','2999-12-12')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('jack',344,'2011-06-27','2012-12-07') 
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('jack',344,'2012-12-01','2015-12-31')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('nick',243,'2012-12-01','2012-12-07')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('joy',234,'2012-12-08','2012-12-14')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('tim',364,'2012-12-25','2012-12-30')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('tim',364,'2013-01-15','2013-01-30')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('jerry',365,'2011-9-15','2012-12-31')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('jerry',365,'2013-01-15','2013-01-30')
INSERT INTO #BenfitDim VALUES('jerry',365,'2011-01-15','2012-01-30')

SELECT MemberKey,
       MemberName,
       DATEADD(DAY,1,T1.MemberTerminationDate)AS MemberEffectiveDate,
       DATEADD(DAY,-1,D.MemberEffectiveDate)AS MemberTerminationDate
FROM
       #BenfitDim AS T1 CROSS APPLY(
                                SELECT MIN(MemberEffectiveDate)AS MemberEffectiveDate
                                  FROM #BenfitDim AS T
                                  WHERE T.MemberEffectiveDate > T1.MemberEffectiveDate 
                                  AND T.MemberKey = T1.MemberKey)D
 WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,T1.MemberTerminationDate) <>  D.MemberEffectiveDate
```

Once you execute you will find the missing sequence but still there is slight problem. how do we take care of an overlap data of "jack" in the table and get the missing sequence right .
your help is appreciated.

Comment: The query doesn't actually execute as you have an error on the line WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,T1.MemberTerminationDate)  D.MemberEffectiveDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query below does what you're looking for. For each membership record it gets the next membership, where the next membership doesn't begin the following day and there isn't an overlapping membership.

The `MIN` and `GROUP BY` are required to get just the date of the next record, rather than all the future records.

```
SELECT      T1.MemberKey,
            T1.MemberName,
            DATEADD(DAY,1,T1.MemberTerminationDate) AS MemberEffectiveDate,
            MIN(DATEADD(DAY,-1,T2.MemberEffectiveDate)) AS MemberTerminationDate

-- current membership
FROM        #BenfitDim AS T1

-- later membership
INNER JOIN  #BenfitDim AS T2                    
ON          T2.MemberKey = T1.MemberKey         
AND         T2.MemberEffectiveDate > T1.MemberTerminationDate

-- no membership following next day or overlapping
WHERE       NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT  T3.MemberEffectiveDate,
                    T3.MemberTerminationDate
            FROM    #BenfitDim AS T3
            WHERE   T3.Memberkey = T1.Memberkey
            AND     (T3.MemberEffectiveDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,T1.MemberTerminationDate)
            OR      T3.MemberEffectiveDate < T1.MemberEffectiveDate
            AND     T3.MemberTerminationDate > T1.MemberEffectiveDate))

GROUP BY    T1.MemberKey,
            T1.MemberName,
            T1.MemberTerminationDate
```